# Android textIsSelectable stops TextView onClick working correctly

Tags: android, onclicklistener, materialcardview

In my current Android application I have a `MaterialCardView` that wraps a `TextView` that I wish to be copyable e.g. I use

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

However, I also need to know when the `MaterialCardView` is clicked as its within a `RecyclerView` Item layout.

My `onClickListener` for the `MaterialCardView` is only triggered when I remove the `android:textIsSelectable="true"` attribute from the child `TextView`.

here is the complete RecyclerView Item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_bibtext_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/colorSurface"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bibtex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

How can I both detect clicks on the Parent `MaterialCardView` and have the child `TextView` selectable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case (with `textIsSelectable="true"`) the `TextView` will still trigger an `OnClick` event. So you could simply add an `OnClickListener` to your `TextView` and link that to the existing CardView click behavior.

Would that cover your case?

Comment: This does allow me to capture the TextView clicks however the user has to click twice before the click is "triggered"